# How to get the ID field over a number of objects

Tags: junction-object

I have the following set up. Bold text indicates an object, underneath are the fields of that object.

**Policy__c**

Source_Opportunity__c (Lookup to Opportunity)

**Policy_Coverage__c**

Policy__c(Lookup to Policy__c)

**Section_Address_Link__c** (Junction Object)

Policy_Coverage__c (Lookup to Policy_Coverage__c)

Section_Address__c (Lookup to Section_Address__c)

**Section_Address__c**

In my code I have a for loop, and I am looping through `Section_Address__c`

```
 for(Section_Address__c dRec:mapSectionAddress.values()){
            Id SourceOppId = dRec.Policy_Coverage__r.Policy__r.Source_Opportunity__c;
        }
```

My code currently assumes that Section Address is a child of policy coverage, but I have changed the db structure and included the junction object. I am now unsure how to change this piece of code correctly.

Tia.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to share more details like if if this code is in a class or a trigger (before/after), if your provided for loop is truncated, and details about the mapSectionAddress map.

Depending on the answer to those questions, you generally need to determine the Ids of the Section_Address__c records in mapSectionAddress.values() - either through a loop before dumping each Section_Address__c.Id into a set or maybe mapSectionAddress is a map where the Id is the Section_Address__c record Id, in which you can just use mapSectionAddress.keyset().

Once you determine those Ids, you'll need to build a query to retrieve the Policy_Coverage records based on the Ids being found in Section_Address_Link__c.Section_Address__c.   That query should include Policy__r.Source_Opportunity__c.  Using those results, you can update your loop to value SourceOppId accordingly.

Pretty vague guidance, but if you need more help, we'll need the answers to those questions and/or some more code.